# Speed up network selection

Tags: mobile-network, roaming

I am living on the border between two countries and consequently I often have to manually select a network, either from one country or from the other country. My issue is that searching for the network is an extremely slow process, that can take up to ten minutes.

Why is this such a slow process?

Are there any ways of speeding it up?

Why do I need to wait for the search to finish completely before I am allowed to choose a network? I would imagine that the phone finds most networks quickly, but then perhaps struggles on a few where the reception is bad, which then increases the time. However, I do not care about finding all the possible networks, just the two main ones that are the ones that I frequently use.

Could I perhaps manually set a timeout for the search of, say, 30 seconds?

I am using a Motorola G7 power with Android 10, but this issue has been with me for several different phones and android versions.